# Can Perl method calls be intercepted?

Tags: perl, subroutine

Can you intercept a method call in Perl, do something with the arguments, and then execute it?

Comment: I see you used the tag "aop".  Why not ask about specific AOP techniques you'd like to use?  (The answers to your question may help you implement an AOP system, but why do that when someone else has already done it?)

Comment: I thought this could be done with method attributes, but now I cannot find the appropriate perldoc page (perldoc attributes is not the page I was thinking of). I recall a nice example involving wrapping various methods for adding in logging...

Comment: See this related SO question for additional info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635212/how-i-redefine-perl-class-methods

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can intercept Perl subroutine calls. I have an entire chapter about that sort of thing in [Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org). Check out the [Hook::LexWrap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Hook-LexWrap) module, which lets you do it without going through all of the details. Perl's methods are just subroutines.

You can also create a subclass and override the method you want to catch. That's a slightly better way to do it because that's the way object-oriented programming wants you do to it. However, sometimes people write code that doesn't allow you to do this properly. There's more about that in [Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org) too.

Answer (score 7):

To describe briefly, Perl has the aptitude to modify symbol table.  You call a subroutine (method) via symbol table of the package, to which the method belongs.  If you modify the symbol table (and this is not considered very dirty), you can substitute most method calls with calling the other methods you specify.  This demonstrates the approach:

```
# The subroutine we'll interrupt calls to
sub call_me
{
    print shift,"\n";
}

# Intercepting factory
sub aspectate
{
    my $callee = shift;
    my $value = shift;
    return sub { $callee->($value + shift); };
}
my $aspectated_call_me = aspectate \&call_me, 100;

# Rewrite symbol table of main package (lasts to the end of the block).
# Replace "main" with the name of the package (class) you're intercepting
local *main::call_me = $aspectated_call_me;

# Voila!  Prints 105!
call_me(5);
```

This also shows that, once someone takes reference of the subroutine and calls it via the reference, you can no longer influence such calls.

I am pretty sure there are frameworks to do aspectation in perl, but this, I hope, demonstrates the approach.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a job for [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.89/lib/Moose/Manual.pod)!  Moose is an object system for Perl that can do that and lots more.  The [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.89/) will do a much better job at explaining than I can, but what you'll likely want is a [Method Modifier](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.89/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod), specifically `before`.

Comment: Moose is something you use for the entire application, not targeted problems.

Comment: But it depends on what the problem is, and the asker of the question doesn't state any details. It might be someone evaluating an approach to take when creating a new application in which case being turned on to Moose would be an appropriate and beneficial response.

Comment: We just said the same thing. I didn't say not to use Moose, but I didn't say to use it either.

Answer (score 5):

You can, and Pavel describes a good way to do it, but you should probably elaborate as to why you are wanting to do this in the first place.

If you're looking for advanced ways of intercepting calls to arbitrary subroutines, then fiddling with symbol tables will work for you, but if you want to be adding functionality to functions perhaps exported to the namespace you are currently working in, then you might need to know of ways to call functions that exist in other namespaces.

Data::Dumper, for example, normally exports the function 'Dumper' to the calling namespace, but you can override or disable that and provide your own Dumper function which then calls the original by way of the fully qualified name.

e.g.

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub Dumper {
   warn 'Dumping variables';
   print Data::Dumper::Dumper(@_);
}

my $foo = {
   bar   => 'barval',
};

Dumper($foo);
```

Again, this is an alternate solution that may be more appropriate depending on the original problem. A lot of fun can be had when playing with the symbol table, but it may be overkill and could lead to hard to maintain code if you don't need it.

Comment: In this case, you should give an empty import list to Dumper so you don't import anything. Also, sequence matters in this case. You have to import first, then override. The last subroutine definition wins. Finally, under warnings, you'll get a 'redefine' error doing this.

Comment: Definitely, just trying to keep it simple for the sake of example. Being direct has more value (and is quicker for the responder) than explaining every tangential detail. The concepts of importing and warnings would be best explained as other questions anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You need three things:

The arguments to a call are in `@_` which is just another dynamically scoped variable.

Then, `goto` supports a reference-sub argument which preserves the current `@_` but makes another (tail) function call.

Finally `local` can be used to create lexically scoped global variables, and the symbol tables are buried in `%::`.

So you've got:

```
sub foo {
    my($x,$y)=(@_);
    print "$x / $y = " . ((0.0+$x)/$y)."\n";
}
sub doit {
    foo(3,4);
}
doit();
```

which of course prints out:

```
3 / 4 = 0.75
```

We can replace foo using `local` and go:

```
my $oldfoo = \&foo;
local *foo = sub { (@_)=($_[1], $_[0]); goto $oldfoo; };
doit();
```

And now we get:

```
4 / 3 = 1.33333333333333
```

If you wanted to modify `*foo` without using its name, and you didn't want to use `eval`, then you could modify it by manipulating `%::`, for example:

```
$::{"foo"} = sub { (@_)=($_[0], 1); goto $oldfoo; };
doit();
```

And now we get:

```
3 / 1 = 3
```