# Is it possible to route Perl's print method

Tags: perl, intercept

Have a look here
[Can Perl method calls be intercepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364734/can-perl-method-calls-be-intercepted)

It shows how to rewrite the symbol table for a simple sub. The print command can take a list I believe, so what is the right way to intercept/rewrite it?  I wish to get a program to delay printing while maintaining the same signature, and instead push the output into an array, pre-sort it, then regurgitate all the output at the very end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intercepting `print` itself isn't the way to go -- it has a number of operating modes, including writing to a file or socket. Instead, take a look at the [`select` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html), which can be used to change the default filehandle which `print` will write to.

Also, look at the concept of a "tied" IO handle, as used by [IO::Capture](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aCapture).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a difference between `print "fun($abc $def)"` and `print("fun($abc $def)")` ? I know I should get a book and I probably will, but this is for a crash course

Comment: No -- they're absolutely 100% equivalent.

Comment: Thanks I thought there's some magic happening with the () like '' and "" are different in PHP. You're been a great help!

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi, Parens can *usually* be omitted, so they are *usually* the same, but they are not 100% equivalent. `print("foo") && 4` vs `print "foo" && 4`, for example.

Comment: I wrote a module [Tie::Select](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Select) which lets you localize the select call to a block. IMO its very useful.