# Printing addresses of Perl object methods? (for redefining Perl class methods)

Tags: perl, reference, memory-address

I saw [How can I redefine Perl class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635212/how-can-i-redefine-perl-class-methods), so I wanted to understand better how it works through an example. (Related: [How do I reference methods? - PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=62737))

If I have an object `$obj` which is an instance of some `Class` which has `Class::method`, then `$obj` also has `$obj->method`; I assume the simplified memory layout in that case would look something like this (tables made in [LaTeX Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables#); for the below one, [src here](https://www.writelatex.com/read/gxwsnjzdxwbg)):

[image: table1]

... that is, at (say) address 0x1000 we have the `$obj->method`, which would simply (somehow) point to the actual `Class::method` definition, which is (say) at 0x3500.

Let's say then I have a `sub` defined somewhere in the main file, `somefunc` (ignore the prefixed $ in the tables), whose definition ends up at address 0x2000.

If I "monkey-patch"/replace the method only for the `$obj` instance, I'd expect the memory layout to look something like this ([src here](https://www.writelatex.com/read/cphsjhfphvtk)):

[image: table2]

Now the thing is this - in the example below (stuff is named more uniquely than in above tables), I actually want to replace the entire class method `Demo::My::Functions::test_me` with a method defined in the main file `repl_test_me`. I don't really know what to expect of addresses, so I'm trying to show what I think are addresses before and after the method patching, using the `%p` specifier of `printf`. The code outputs this:

```
$ perl cltest.pl 
Starting Demo::Main...
Orig test_me!
1: DMFo: 8e63dc0 DMFo->test_me 8e916f8 DMF::test_me 8e916e8 repl_test_me 8e91748
Orig test_me!
-- CODE --
Subroutine Demo::My::Functions::test_me redefined at cltest.pl line 59.
Repl test_me!
Repl test_me!
2: DMFo: 8e63dc0 DMFo->test_me 8e916f8 DMF::test_me 8dfb708 repl_test_me 8dfb6c8
```

What is weird here, is that even the function that is defined in the main file, `repl_test_me`, changes address - and it shouldn't?!

So, I'm apparently not printing what I think are addresses of functions - and I think it's also confirmed by the fact that I have two printouts per each call, while I should have only one?

How can I change the below code, so I print out the addresses that can help me confirm that the patching/overloading happened as expected?

Here is the code, `cltest.pl`:

```
use v5.10.1;

package Demo::My::Functions;
$INC{'Demo/My/Functions.pm'} = 1;

use warnings;
use strict;

use base 'Class::Accessor';

__PACKAGE__->mk_accessors(qw(test_me));

sub test_me {
  my $self = shift;
  print("Orig test_me!\n");
  return 1;
}

sub test_also_me {
  my $self = shift;
  print("Orig test_also_me!\n");
  return 1;
}

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {};
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}

############################################################
package Demo::Main;


use warnings;
use strict;
print("Starting Demo::Main...\n");

my $DMFA = Demo::My::Functions->new();

sub repl_test_me {
  my $self = shift;
  print("Repl test_me!\n");
  return 1;
}

# note: \&{$DMFA->test_me} calls!
printf("1: DMFo: %p DMFo->test_me %p DMF::test_me %p repl_test_me %p\n",
      $DMFA, \&{$DMFA->test_me}, \&{'Demo::My::Functions::test_me'}, \&repl_test_me
);

print("-- " . ref(\&{$DMFA->test_me}) . " --\n");

{
no strict 'refs';
#~ *Demo::My::Functions::test_me = sub {my $self = shift; print("ReplIN test_me!\n"); return 1; }; # OK
#~ *Demo::My::Functions::test_me = *repl_test_me; # overloads
*Demo::My::Functions::test_me = \&repl_test_me; # overloads
};

# test it:
$DMFA->test_me();

# output addr again:
printf("2: DMFo: %p DMFo->test_me %p DMF::test_me %p repl_test_me %p\n",
      $DMFA, \&{$DMFA->test_me}, \&{'Demo::My::Functions::test_me'}, \&repl_test_me
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects don't have methods; classes do. An object is simply a variable with a package associated with it.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -E'$o={}; Dump($o); bless($o); Dump($o); say \%main::'
SV = IV(0x26c2360) at 0x26c2370
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (ROK)
  RV = 0x269a978
  SV = PVHV(0x26a0400) at 0x269a978
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x0
    KEYS = 0
    FILL = 0
    MAX = 7
SV = IV(0x26c2360) at 0x26c2370
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (ROK)
  RV = 0x269a978
  SV = PVHV(0x26a0400) at 0x269a978
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (OBJECT,SHAREKEYS)
    STASH = 0x269a7f8   "main"
    ARRAY = 0x0
    KEYS = 0
    FILL = 0
    MAX = 7
HASH(0x269a7f8)    # Address of the main package.
```

So the real layout is

```
                +---------+
                |         |
                |         v
+-----------+   |   +-----------+
| Reference |   |   | 0x269a7f8 |
| 0x26c2370 |   |   | Package   |
+-----------+   |   +-----------+
      |         |         |
  References    |     Contains
      |         |         |
      v         |         v
+-----------+   |   +-----------+
| Hash      |   |   | 0xXXXXXXX |
| 0x269a978 |   |   | Method    |
+-----------+   |   +-----------+
      |         |
Blessed into    |
      |         |
      +---------+
```

Changing the package affects all objects that use that package.

```
$ perl -E'
   sub f { "a" }
   my $o = bless({});
   say join " ", \&f, $o->can("f"), $o->f;
   *f = sub { "b" };
   say join " ", \&f, $o->can("f"), $o->f;
'
CODE(0x311c680) CODE(0x311c680) a
CODE(0x3126f60) CODE(0x3126f60) b
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @ikegami - this precisely points out what I was missing in my thinking in the OP; will have to study it closer. Cheers!

Comment: Actually, a class with a suitable [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) routine *could* have objects with methods.  But that's not how it normally works in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

> *I'm apparently not printing what I think are addresses of functions*

Right.  Instead, you're `printf("%p")`ing the address of a (temporary and unnamed) variable holding the reference to the subroutine.  (In C, you'd have printed the address of the pointer, rather than its contents.)

---

> *[How can I] I print out the addresses [of the subs]?*

`\&a_sub` returns the thing you're interested in.  To inspect it, just print it, as it stringifies (and numifies) nicely and will reveal the address:

```
use feature qw(say);

sub f {}
my $f_ref = \&f;
say "reference: $f_ref"; # reference: CODE(0x1234)
```

---

> *I have two printouts per each call, while I should have only one[.]*

Yes.  When you say this:

```
\&{$object->method}
```

You are invoking *method* (which is one of your printouts) and then taking a reference to the CODE slot of its stringified return value in the symbol table.  In your case, that's a reference to a non-existent subroutine named `1`, which is what your subs return.  (That is, it's as if you'd said `my $coderef = \&{1}`.)  I'm surprised this gets past `strict` and `warnings` without comment, for what it's worth.

Comment: many thanks for that, @pilcrow - all of those are extremely crucial  points you've noted (and which I was missing)! I already accepted ikegami's answer, but +1: this post is just as important for me. Thanks again - cheers!