# Call subroutine automatically whenever cursor position changes in a Text widget

Tags: perl, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am using the [`Tk::Text`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tk%3a%3aText) module.

I want that whenever the user changes the position of the cursor inside the `Tk::Text` module, it should act as a trigger to call a subroutine which I have written.

How do I go about implementing this?

**EDIT:**

As answered by Donal Fellows, I somehow need to find if the `insert` mark is changed when a call is made to the `markSet` routine. I have searched the net extensively to find a solution to this problem, but to no avail. Now I need you guys to help me with it. Thanks!

Comment: We need a lot more information. Which `Text` module do you mean? And please show your relevant code.

Comment: @Borodin I am talking about the Tk::Text module.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a predefined callback for when the location of the `insert` mark changes (that's the terminology you're looking for) but it is *always* set via the `markSet` method. Maybe you can put something in to intercept calls to that method, see if they're being applied to `insert`, and do your callback? (That's certainly how I'd do it in Tcl/Tk; I don't know how easy it is to intercept methods on the Perl side of things but surely it must be possible?)

Comment: Is there any way to change the `markSet` method in Perl/Tk?

Comment: @LiamWillis I don't know, but if there isn't I'm _very_ startled. Perl's usually good for such tricky things…

Answer (score 1):

This is what https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356444/2335842 is talking about, see http://p3rl.org/perlobj and http://p3rl.org/Tk::Widget and  http://p3rl.org/require for details

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use Tk;
Main( @ARGV );
exit( 0 );

BEGIN {
    package Tk::TText;
    $INC{q{Tk/TText.pm}}=__FILE__;
    use parent qw[ Tk::Text ];
    Tk::Widget->Construct( q{TText} );
    sub markSet {
        warn qq{@_};
        my( $self, @args ) = @_;
        $self->SUPER::markSet( @args );
    }
}

sub Main {
    my $mw = tkinit();
    $mw->TText->pack;
    use Tk::WidgetDump; $mw->WidgetDump; ## helps you Tk your Tk
    $mw->MainLoop;
}
__END__
Tk::TText=HASH(0x10f7a74) insert @347,218 at - line 13.
Tk::TText=HASH(0x10f7a74) anchor insert at - line 13.
```

Comment: Can you expain what `BEGIN { ... }` is doing in a bit more detail?

Comment: the BEGIN block hook on `markSet` method to allow you to inject code  when it is called. This is known as monkey patching. The proposed solution alter the package TText and will hook on every subsequently created intances. For per instance monkey patching, you might give a glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449690/how-can-i-monkey-patch-an-instance-method-in-perl

Comment: not monkeypatching, its a right proper subclass ... the links explain the details